# How can I loop and output original value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am printing values to the output but I am not sure how to grab the original value before it was updated and display it.

```
declare
    v_ids varchar2(4000); 

   begin

   update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
    where tl.limit_template IN
       (select tl.limit_template
          from base_timeline_section bbts,
               base_timeline_org     bts,
               trmt_timeline         tl
         where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
           and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
           and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720')
       returning listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group 
                     (order by tl.limit_template) into v_ids;
     dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');
     end;
```

Right now I get the following output: Updated IDs:

LIM0178 to LIM0178

What i want is

original value: 6165 changed to new value: LIM0178

---

```
 declare
    v_ids varchar2(4000); 
    v_ids2 varchar2(4000);
   begin
    select listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group (order by 
    tl.limit_template) into v_ids
      from base_timeline_section bbts,
           base_timeline_org     bts,
           trmt_timeline         tl
     where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
       and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
       and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720';

update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
 where tl.limit_template IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_ids, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                               from (select rownum from dual ) 
                            connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(v_ids,'[^,]*'))+1);


 dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');


  select listagg(iplu.limit_template_id, ',') within group (order by iplu.limit_template_id)into v_ids2
  from base_timeline_section bbts,
       base_timeline_org     bts,
       trmt_timeline         tl,
       timeline_update_limit iplu
   where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
   and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
   and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720'
   and iplu.limit_template_id = tl.limit_template;


update timeline_update_limit iplu
   set iplu.limit_template_id = 'LIM178'
where iplu.limit_template_id IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (v_ids2, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                        from (select rownum from dual ) 
                        connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(v_ids2,'[^,]*'))+1);

  dbms_output.put_line('Update table 2 IDs: ' || v_ids2 || ' to LIM0178');


  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before updating you can place your value in one variable and use it as per your need.
You may find this link for more info. [LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm).

```
DECLARE
   the_variable NUMBER;    --- this is varaible declare
declare
    v_ids varchar2(4000); 

   begin

   SELECT limit_template INTO the_variable FROM time_line --- here we are setting its value
   where tl.limit_template IN
       (select tl.limit_template
          from base_timeline_section bbts,
               base_timeline_org     bts,
               trmt_timeline         tl
         where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
           and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
           and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720')
       returning listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group 
                     (order by tl.limit_template) into v_ids;
     dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');;

   update time_line tl
   set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
    where tl.limit_template IN
       (select tl.limit_template
          from base_timeline_section bbts,
               base_timeline_org     bts,
               trmt_timeline         tl
         where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
           and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
           and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720')
       returning listagg(tl.limit_template, ',') within group 
                     (order by tl.limit_template) into v_ids;
     dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');
     end;
```

I am not sure about the syntax, you can check more on that and correct this ans if found any mistake.

Comment: unfortunately when I try this I get a ORA-01422: fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: that means there are more then one values in `limit_template` column, which you are updating. Please verify this query individually to apply filter as per the record needed. or use distinct to get the record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can break your statement and return the values into a variable and pass the variable to update the values as it is comma separated it can be a list of values, this way it will execute the selection :-

```
   declare
    v_ids  clob; 
    v_ids2 clob;
   begin
    select RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,tl.limit_template,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY tl.limit_template).GetClobVal(),',') into v_ids
      from base_timeline_section bbts,
           base_timeline_org     bts,
           trmt_timeline         tl
     where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
       and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
       and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720';

  update time_line tl
     set tl.limit_template = 'LIM0178'
   where tl.limit_template IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (DBMS_LOB.substr(v_ids,30000), '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                               from (select rownum from dual ) 
                            connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(v_ids,'[^,]*'))+1);


 dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to LIM0178');


  select RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,iplu.limit_template_id,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY iplu.limit_template_id).GetClobVal(),',') into v_ids2
  from base_timeline_section bbts,
       base_timeline_org     bts,
       trmt_timeline         tl,
       timeline_update_limit iplu
   where bbts.base_trmt_set_id = bts.base_trmt_set_id
   and tl.limit_id = bts.limit_id
   and bbts.bse_trmt_st_tplt_id = '720'
   and iplu.limit_template_id = tl.limit_template;


   update timeline_update_limit iplu
      set iplu.limit_template_id = 'LIM178'
    where iplu.limit_template_id IN (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (DBMS_LOB.substr(v_ids2,30000), '[^,]+', 1, level) 
                        from (select rownum from dual ) 
                        connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(v_ids2,'[^,]*'))+1);

  dbms_output.put_line('Update table 2 IDs: ' || v_ids2 || ' to LIM0178');


  end;
```

Comment: thanks im getting a "Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following, begin function pragma procedure subtype –

Comment: @jacques i have update the code as previously i was passing  v_ids directly to update statement which can't work.  The error you encountered might be because of some missing or incorrect bracket, Please try new code and let me know if it works.

Comment: if I have a second table that needs to be updated, it doent seem to populate the list and I am not sure why, I get  Table 1Updated IDs: 13008,13069,13130,13402,13467,13532,13597,13597,13662,13727,13792,13857,13922,13987,14052,14117,14182,14247,14377,14442,14507,14572,14637,14702,14767,14897,14962,15027,15092,15157,15222,15287,15352,15417,15482,15547,15612,16262,16522,16717,16782 to LIM0178
Table 2Updated IDs:  to LIM0178

Comment: if you would share the second table statement, will try to see what's wrong with that.

Comment: so the strange thing is if i exclusively run the second update statement it works fine, it then sets the variable and works perfectly, however if I try and run two updates it only sets the first updates variable.

Comment: @jacques i have checked by running a dummy code  as well , it should work fine as both are independent updates on different tables. Check you might be missing something silly.

Comment: if previous solution worked fine you can accept the answer with up arrow . thanks

Comment: i now seem to be getting a ORA-01489: result of string concatenation too long , any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199067/discussion-between-ramash-and-jacques).